# Share Hibernate Second-Level Cache - Can multiple applications share the same cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache

I have two applications to use the same database with same schema. Application A will read write the table A. Application B will read the table A only.

If I configured 2nd Level cache in both applications. Application B will not retrieve the updated value which application A updated the record in table A before.

I want to configure the same hibernate config to share the same cache with multiple applications (in this case, application B can get the updated value)

I read some stackoverflow but still not work for me.

I am using hibernate 5 and using Ehcache for cache management.

Any idea how I might implement this?  May I have any reference?

Here are some hibernate Properties in my both applications

Sprint hibernate config:

```
 <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Debug -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            <!-- Level two caching -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">../conf/ehcache.xml</prop>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true" >

     <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

     <!-- Default cache settings -->
     <defaultCache
          maxElementsInMemory="100000"
          eternal="true"
          timeToIdleSeconds="300"
          timeToLiveSeconds="300"
          overflowToDisk="false"
          maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
          diskPersistent="false"
          diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="300"
          memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    </defaultCache>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using distributed cache like Hazelcast. In fact Hazelcast has built-in integration with Hibernate to easily plug in for second-level caching